# Expected value of a discrete random variable with $R(X)$ countably infinite

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, expectation

Consider a discrete random variable  with pdf $f(x_k)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2^k}$ with $R(X)$ $\displaystyle\{x_k =(-1)^k\frac{2^k}{k},k=1,2,3...\}$ ,then the sum defining the expectation is 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{x_kf(x_k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{(-1)^k}{k}}=-ln(1+1)=-ln(2)$$

Can someone explain how this sum converges to $-ln(1+1)$ ?

Comment: Note that the expectation, as expectation is usually defined, *does not exist*. For the usual definition of expectation *requires absolute convergence*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you mean that the absolute convergence will ensure the existence , since absolute convergence implies "standard " convergence

Comment: That is not what I mean. When the sum (or integral) does not converge absolutely, but converges, one does not say that the expectation exists. This  is even mentioned in the Wikipedia article on expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...$.
Putting $x=1$, we get $\ln(2)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$. Hence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}=-\ln(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like
$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k}x^k = (-1)\sum_{k = 1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}x^k = -\log (1+x).$$
When $x = 1$, this is equal to $-\log (1+1) = -\log (2).$